# SQL Server Case Subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, case

I have a database table that records staff contacts with clients. Usually only 1 staff member contacts a client, however occasionally 2 staff members have a contact with a client at the same time. One staff member is flagged as the primary, the other the secondary. To provide a link the one flagged as secondary will have the ContactID of the primary stored in the SecondaryContactID field, like in this example:

```
ContactID   SecondaryContactID   ContactDate   StaffMemberID   ContactLocation
---------   ------------------   -----------   -------------   ---------------  
123456      Null                 01/JUL/2013   John            SydneyCBD
123457      123456               01/JUL/2013   James           Null
```

Our major corporate app has a bug in that it does not store the same ContactLocation for the secondary staff member as the primary (even though they are always the same location in reality), its defaulting to Null. So in the example above "SydneyCBD" should be in both rows.

In my extract I need these records on 2 rows pretty much like the example, but how do I get SydneyCBD to print instead of Null...some sort of case subquery using the SecondaryContactID as a link?

Comment: In your question post the query that you have now. We'll help you improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT T1.CONTACTID, 
       SECONDARYCONTACTID, 
       CONTACTDATE, 
       STAFFMEMBERID, 
       ISNULL(T1.CONTACTLOCATION, T2.CONTACTLOCATION) ContactLocation 
FROM   TABLE1 T1 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT CONTACTLOCATION, 
                         CONTACTID 
                  FROM   TABLE1)T2 
              ON T1.SECONDARYCONTACTID = T2.CONTACTID
```

A working example can be found on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9929b/3).